# NoMethodError: undefined method `configure' for AjaxDatatablesRails:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

When I execute `rake db:create` command it will display some error's

```
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `configure' for AjaxDatatablesRails:Module
/home/jsmani/project-folder/config/initializers/ajax_datatables_rails.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:60:in `load'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:60:in `load'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:663:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:662:in `load_config_initializer'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:620:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `each'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
/home/jsmani/project-folder/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/skylight-5.1.0/lib/skylight/probes.rb:167:in `require'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/jsmani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: check comment on this [issue](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails/issues/380) in `ajax-datatables-rails` gem

Comment: when i comment ajax-datatables-rails gem it will produce name error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **gemfile** give some specific version for **AjaxDataTablesRails** like (**gem 'ajax-datatables-rails', '~> 1.0.0'**) instead of giving (**gem 'ajax-datatables-rails'**) like this.
After save this changes let execute this command (**bundle install**) on your terminal .
And now you execute **rake db:create** command .
and do following command **rake db:migrate** then start your server **rails s**